# How to fix jslint warnings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I am using jslint for fixing jslint violations. Here I fixed the violations and ignore the files in JSLint.net.json file.

After this, when I build the projects, I saw the warnings in jslint net json file.

Warnings: Missing a comma after an array element.  How do I fix this warnings?

My JSlintNet json file:

```
{
   "version":  "2.3.0",
   "output": "Warning",
   "module": true,
   "ignore": [
     "\\Scripts\\Menu\\fileone.js",
     "\\Scripts\\Menu\\filetwo.js",
     "\\Scripts\\Others\\filethree.js",
     "\\Scripts\\Others\\filefour.js",
     "\\Scripts\\Others\\filefive.js",
     "\\Scripts\\Others\\filesix.js",
     "\\Scripts\\Others\\fileseven.js",
     "\\Scripts\\Others\\fileeight.js"

  ],
 "options": {
 "this": true,
 "for": true,
 "browser": true,
 "single": true,
 "devel": true,
 "sloppy": true

},
"globalVariables": [
  "$",
  "swal",
  "window"

],
"runOnBuild": false,
"cancelBuild": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using **eslint** which has a feature to auto fix few linting errors.

Example :

> eslint -c .eslintrc --fix ./src/scripts/**/*.js

eslintrc is json file with rules.

Besides this **prettier** can be used to auto fix indentation error.

> prettier --print-width 120 --tab-width 4 --single-quote --trailing-comma none --write --parser babylon ./src/scripts/**/*.js

If you will run prettier then eslint auto fix, most of the common lint error will be solved automatically. Rest of the error requires manual code change

Reference [Eslint](http://eslint.org/) [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier)

Further it can be linked to Package.json

```
`"eslint": "eslint -c .eslintrc --fix ./src/scripts/**/*.js || exit 0",
 "prettier": "prettier --print-width 120 --tab-width 4 --single-quote --trailing-comma none --write --parser babylon ./src/scripts/**/*.js || exit 0"`
```